# Why i am forced to use NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in iOS10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, photolibrary

I have an application which does work mainly with map, it also uses Realm to work with data and few more of small libs. Until i was compiling for iOS9 everything was fine, then i upgraded xcode, now i am compiling for iOS10.

Since then, when i tried to upload beta build to testflight, this build didn't appear there and i received email from apple with text like:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "XY app". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

Now, i am not aware that i do work with photo library.. So the question is, do you know why this thing happens? I am using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to store some images in the cache, if this is causing the problem i don't know.

So now i am in funny situation to describe the reason why do i use the user photo library but i am not aware that my app does use it, so what should i write there.

How could i find which part of app is working with photo library?

I don't use camera, i don't browser user photos, i am using only MKMapView, location service using CLLocationManager, Realm to work with data and SDWebImage as i said.

**Btw, now i realized that i have also zendesk widget for tech support and there is a function which allows to take photo or browse user photos, perhaps this could be the source of problems.**

Thx

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in your last paragraph there.

Comment: Yes.. maybe it will help someone who knows.

Comment: I just don't understand why Zendesk might need camera access. Photo-access, sure! - to send screenshots for Support tickets. But the camera? Why?